# Rails 4 + BootStrap 4 button issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I have a quick question I can't actually get a bootstrap 4 button to work in rails this is my button code

```
<%= link_to 'LifeHacks', controller: 'hacks', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

I thought that would work but it ends up being apart of the url instead like this "http://localhost/hacks?class=btn+btn-primary"

Comment: Try this `<%= link_to 'LifeHacks', controller: 'hacks', { class: 'btn btn-primary'} %>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any enclosing braces, ruby will treat the last two parts of your method parameters as a single hash when in actual fact they should be two.

Wrapping your route parameters in braces will resolve your issue:

```
<%= link_to 'LifeHacks', {controller: 'hacks'}, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

From the documentation, you can see how these are defined:

> link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)

Without any explicit wrapping, both your `controller` and `class` options were being passed as `options` rather than the `class` element being passed as `html_options`.

Comment: Thank you for going into detail as well and thanks for the answer it worked will mark as the answer as soon as I can.